# "By way of contrast VS By ways of comparing"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, difference, phrase-usage, usage

What is the difference between these two phrases?

Do they have the same meaning or not?

e.g "Elephants are very tall. By way of contrast, the insects are small."

e.g "I study language by ways of comparing books."

Are they true or not?

Comment: You need to add more context. There are many differences in their meaning, and the answer will be too broad unless you have some context or specific difference in mind.

Comment: Can you give me sentences for each of them? And explain your answer in the sentence? I think it's good

Answer (score 1):

> By way of contrast, [some phrase]."

*By way of contrast* is a regular prepositional phrase.

An example [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrast):

> They spent millions of dollars on advertising. **By way of contrast**, our small company spent under 5,000 dollars.

vs.

> By ways of comparing (x and y), [some phrase]."

*By ways of comparing (x and y)* is a noun phrase.

I could not find any examples, so this might not be a normally used form.